# Entity Framework Core Migration in Azure Pipeline

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, yaml, azure-pipelines

Does anyone know why a connectionString is required when running ef migration from YAML and not Developer Command Prompt?

I believe it might have something to do with not pulling the connectionString value from the Pipeline Variable.

I am setting the connection string here:

```
builder.Service.AddDbContext<myContext>(options=>
  options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB")));
```

I have tried my Pipeline Variable's names as

```
MyDB
ConnectionStrings_MyDB
ConnectionStrings:MyDB
```

The following YAML gives me the error "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')"

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Create SQL Scripts
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: 'ef '
    arguments: migrations script --output $(sqlOutputPath) --idempotent --project $(solution)
```

However running the following command from Developer Command Prompt executes successfully:

```
dotnet ef migrations script --output complete.sql --idempotent --project myproject
```

Comment: Do you have variables `sqlOutputPath` and `solution` defined? If yes, are you sure that `solution` has correct value?

Comment: Yes, it throws an project not found exception if it can't find the project.

Comment: Well I'm asking because your variable suggest that you use rather solution name. Are you sure that `solution` is a project name?

Comment: I am positive because the project builds successfully. This parameter can be used for solutions and projects.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that I forgot to add the reference for Azure KeyVault to my project; therefore it was not even looking at keyvault for the ConnectionString. Also the name would need to be ConnectionStrings--MyDB